# C++ Предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию. Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-проектирования, map

SquareGrid.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef SQUARE_GRID_H
#define  SQUARE_GRID_H

#include <set>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

struct SPODGridPosition
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator < (const SPODGridPosition & x1, const SPODGridPosition & x2);

bool operator == (const SPODGridPosition & x1, const SPODGridPosition & x2);

bool operator != (const SPODGridPosition & x1, const SPODGridPosition & x2);

struct SSquareGrid
{
    typedef  SPODGridPosition Location;
    static std::array<Location, 4> m_dirs;
    std::set<Location> m_wallsSet;

    SSquareGrid(int width, int height)
        : m_width(width)
        , m_height(height)
    {

    }
    void AddOrDeleteWall(int x, int y)
    {
        Location next{ x,y };
        auto iter = m_wallsSet.find(next);
        if ( iter != m_wallsSet.end())
        {
            m_wallsSet.erase(iter);
        }
        m_wallsSet.insert(next);
    }
    bool InBounds(const Location & id) const
    {
        return 0 < id.x && id.x < m_width && 0 < id.y && id.y < m_height;
    }
    bool Passable(const Location & id) const
    {
        return m_wallsSet.find(id) != m_wallsSet.end();
    }
    std::vector<Location> Neighbors(Location id) const
    {
        std::vector<Location> result;
        for (auto const dir : m_dirs)
        {
            Location next{ id.x + dir.x, id.y + dir.y };
            if (InBounds(next) && Passable(next))
            {
                result.push_back(next);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
};

extern SSquareGrid g_SquareGrid;

#endif // !SQUARE_GRID_H
```

SquarGrid.cpp

```
#include "SquareGrid.h"

SSquareGrid g_SSquareGrid(30, 30);

bool operator < (const SPODGridPosition & x1, const SPODGridPosition & x2)
{
    return std::tie(x1.x, x1.y) < std::tie(x2.x, x2.y);
}

bool operator == (const SPODGridPosition & x1, const SPODGridPosition & x2)
{
    return x1.x == x2.x && x1.y == x2.y;
}

bool operator != (const SPODGridPosition & x1, const SPODGridPosition & x2)
{
    return !(x1 == x2);
}
```

FindPath.h

```
#pragma once

#include "SquareGrid.h"

template <typename Graph, typename Location>
std::unordered_map<Location, Location> BreadthFirstSearch(const Graph & graph, Location start, Location goal);

void FindPath(int n32SelfX, int n32SelfY, int n32TargetX, int n32TargetY);
```

FindPath.cpp

```
#include "FindPath.h"

std::array<SPODGridPosition, 4> SSquareGrid::m_dirs = { SPODGridPosition{0,1},
SPODGridPosition{1,0}, SPODGridPosition{0,-1}, SPODGridPosition{-1,0} };

template <typename Graph, typename Location>
std::unordered_map<Location, Location>  BreadthFirstSearch(const Graph & graph, Location start, Location goal)
{
    std::queue<Location> frontier;
    frontier.push(start);
    std::unordered_map<Location, Location> came_from;
    came_from[start] = start;
    while (!frontier.empty())
    {
        auto current = frontier.front();
        frontier.pop();
        if (current == goal) break;
        for (auto & next : graph.Neighbors(current))
        {
            frontier.push(next);
            came_from[next] = current;
        }
    }
    return came_from;
}

void FindPath(int n32SelfX, int n32SelfY, int n32TargetX, int n32TargetY)
{
    auto came_from = BreadthFirstSearch(g_SquareGrid, SPODGridPosition{ n32SelfX, n32SelfY },
        SPODGridPosition{ n32TargetX, n32TargetY });
}
```

**Ошибка** :    C2280   "std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию   MyGame  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\unordered_map   132

**Замечание** : Если содержимое FindPath удалить, то компилируется.

Comment: А на какую строку ругается-то?

Comment: Не, на какую строку в вашем коде ругается компилятор? Дайте _полное_ сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Ошибка C2280 "std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию MyGame c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\unordered_map 132

Comment: 1) Ещё полнее, пожалуйста. Там должен быть контекст ошибки. 2) И лучше класть это не в комментарий, а в вопрос (там есть ссылка «править»).

Comment: 1) Это все информация. Больше VC 17 мне ничего не выдает. 2) Я же в конце вопроса разместил.

Comment: Если содержимое функции FindPath убрать, то компилируется.

Comment: 1) Не может быть. Вы заглядывали в окошко Output?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280

Comment: _`std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)`_ - это что, @VladD? Конструктор копирования хэша?

Comment: Комментируй её по строчке и смотри, какая строка вызывает ошибку.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это ж кресты. Какая-то внутренняя функция в шаблоне не скомилировалась. Что это означает — надо смотреть в окне Output, там написан контекст ошибки.

Comment: for (auto & next : graph.Neighbors(current))...  а вы можете ссылаться на внутренность некой неизвестной функции_члена?..

Comment: Это может и не поможет, но на всякий случай спрошу: Любопытно - зачем здесь _`template <typename Graph, typename Location> std::unordered_map<Location, Location> BreadthFirstSearch(const Graph & graph, Location start, Location goal);`_ вообше нужен первый аргумент шаблона и первый аргумент функции, если вы и без этого имеете глобальный константный обьект `SSquareGrid g_SSquareGrid(30, 30),`
и именно его и используете как аргумент?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan   1) Функция Neighbors определена же, когда первый раз опечатался компилятор ругался на неизвестную функцию. 2) Там, откуда я код брал был определен ещё один Graph, который также мог взаимодействовать с BreadthFirstSearch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не определили hasher для своего `SPODGridPosition`. В результате компилятор подхватывает какую-то свою специализацию `std::hash<SPODGridPosition>` для стандартного `std::hash<>`. А в ней удален конструктор копирования, что и приводит к ошибке где-то в недрах конструкции `unordered_map`.

Это в любом случае не могло работать, ибо как надо хэшить ваш `SPODGridPosition` компилятор не знает. Определите hasher для `SPODGridPosition` и укажите его в качестве третьего параметра шаблона `unordered_map`.

Comment: это скорее всего так и есть

Comment: равенство у него определено

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: А, точно, спасибо. Не заметил сразу.

Comment: @ Qwertiy, да,  не ответ, но  улучшить код тоже полезно